# php: how to redirect to custom url like "blar://abc"

Tags: php

Environment:

- Apache 2.4.34
- PHP 7.2.19
- Chrome 85.0.4183.121

I run codes in localhost.

I want to redirect request to url in other scheme than http or https, like "blar://abc". I run the following code but it doesn't work. Is it right behavior?

```
<?php
    
    $location = 'blar://abc';
    header( "Location: $location" );
    return;
?>
```

I tried to redirect to the folder in my pc by runing the following code. But it doesn't work, either.

```
<?php
   $location = 'C:\test';
   header( "Location: $location" );
   return;
?>
```

Of course, redirect to ordinal web site does work.

```
<?php
$location = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
header( "Location: $location" );
return;
?>
```

Comment: Last time that worked the year number used to start with 1. Try with the URL of some public website (why not `https://stackoverflow.com`?) or use `http://example.org` instead. Nobody will complain.

Comment: @axiac sorry I might not get it. with public website, it works. I want to know if you can redirect to url in other scheme.

Comment: Have you tried `curl`ing the headers/body to see what that `header()` call is actually doing?

Comment: You cannot redirect to a file without using `file://`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski so, should be like `$location = 'file://C:/xampp/';`? it didn't work, though.

Comment: You can redirect to whatever you want. The question is if the visitor of the site (all visitors of the site) have installed a program that can handle the protocol. This limits the usable protocols to `http`, `https`, `mailto` and the old (and less used nowadays) `ftp` protocol.